# Как изменить ссылку?

Tags: php

Как изменить ссылку вида `http://dfn.ru/new.php?id=27` на `http://dfn.ru/mynes.html`?

**Добавлено.**

Хмм, а если я так хочу `http://dfn.ru/id/27.html`? Пробовал писать так `RewriteRule ^id/(.*).html$ new.php?id=$1 [L]`, стили и джава не грузятся.

Comment: Ты имеешь в виду, чтобы вместо http://dfn.ru/new.php?id=27 был адрес http://dfn.ru/mynes.html, но вёл он на туже страницу и он же отображался в адресной строке, иными словами изменить вид ссылок  помощью .htaccess mod_rewrite, я правильно понял?

Comment: Скажите, как это будет спомощью mod_rewrite выглядеть?

Comment: Так:

    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteRule ([^/]*).html index.php?aliace=$1
  
В результате изменится логика обработки, вместо поиска материала по id нужно будет искать по aliace, который должен быть уникальным  
`http://dfn.ru/mynes.html`

    $_GET['aliace'] == 'mynes'

Comment: >стили и джава не грузятся

Пропишите пути от корня сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Создать http://dfn.ru/new.php следущего содержания:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['id']==27) {header ("Location: http://dfn.ru/mynes.html");}
?>
```

Comment: а если у меня их много я ж не буду каждую так делать

Comment: тогда формулируйте точнее то что требуется. я считал что разный ID ведёт на разную страницу...

Comment: Dem уже привёл исправленный вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Немного измененный вариант:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);

$replaces = array(
    27 => '/mynes.html',
    189 => '/mynes2.html',
    368 => '/mynes3.html',
);

header('Location: ' . $replaces[$id]);
```

Comment: и массив хранить в бд;)

Comment: не работает
 он переходит но пишет страница не найдена

Comment: А без редиректа нужная страница открывается?

Comment: не работает код!!! я согласен!!!

Comment: @Dem, может нужно еще что-то в htaccess прописать? а то так не работает?